# Multithread execution on Spring 4 using Reactor 2.0

Tags: java, multithreading, spring, reactor, project-reactor

I'm trying to integrate [Reactor 2x](https://github.com/reactor/reactor/tree/v2.0.1.RELEASE) into an existing `Spring 4` application to boost performance during the execution of a `REST` request where `resources` can be fetched independent from each other, sort of map-reduce where we parallelize a job into multiple threads and then join them into a buffer.

So far we have this sample working in a non-spring environment:

```
    //Ordered resources to apply transformations.
    List<Map<String, Object>> result;

    result = Streams.from(resources)
                    .flatMap(m -> Streams.just(m) .dispatchOn(Environment.cachedDispatcher())
                    .map(resourceToMapFunction::apply))
                    .buffer().next().await(5, TimeUnit.SECONDS);
```

In the sample above, we apply the transformation using the `resourceToMapFunction` and then the join the with the `buffer()` method, create the `Promise` to wait for the result and return the `result`.

My first question, is this the way Reactor is suppose to be used? I know that the transformations are applied correctly but maybe, me being a newbie in `Reactor` not using something the right way.

My second question, is not a big deal but is there anything in the `Reactor` project to return in the same order provided in the `resources` input? Since this is executing in multiple threads I'm pretty sure the answer is not, and like I said is the less of my worries, but wanted to ask anyways.

Last question, when I introduce this code to my `Spring` project the transformations failed because the `Bean` dependencies to apply the underlaying transformations are not in the execution threads, is this something I can do easily with the Spring Reactor version? If so, is there any link or document that shows how to do it?

Thanks a lot!

José Luis

Answer (score 1):

You should use Reactor's API. So instead of creating a Java `Stream` you should create Reactor `Flux`. Then you should use the `flatMap` function of a `Flux` in order to fetch some resources. If you want the resources to be in the same order as requested you can use `flatMapSequential`.

So the code would look like:

```
        Flux<Map<String,Object>> result = Flux.fromIterable(resources)
                .flatMapSequential(resourceToMapFunction::apply)
                .take(Duration.ofSeconds(5));
```

Then you have a Reactor stream and you can apply more operations to that stream. If you'd like to have simple list then you would have to block by using operator `collectList`. If you would like to have a control over a Thread on which given function will be executed then you'd have to get familiar with `Scheduler`.

Answer (score 0):

React library will help a lot. Reactive programming (and async servlets) are supported by Spring 5, not Spring 4.

Spring 4 still supports  some basic async features. It must be sufficient for you case. Here is a small example based on `@EnableAsync` and `CompletableFuture`:

https://dzone.com/articles/multi-threading-in-spring-boot-using-completablefu